# Minimum of parameter integral

Tags: definite-integrals

Find the  minimum value of the function
$f: R \to R, f(x)= \int_{0}^{1} {|x-t|}^3dt$

I computed the function analysing 3 cases:
$x \leq 1, x \in (0,1), x \geq 1 $
And then i studied the extrem with derivatives obtaining that f has $1/2$ as a minimum point.
I am interested if there is a shorter solution without too much computation.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$f'(x)=\int_0^1 \frac{d{|x-t|^3}}{dx}dt=\int_0^13(x-t)^2\text{sign}(x-t)dt=\\
=-(x-t)^3\text{sign}(x-t)\Big|^1_0=x^3\text{sign}(x)-(x-1)^3\text{sign}(x-1)$

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(x)= \int_{0}^{1} {|x-t|}^3dt$ it follows that

\begin{eqnarray}
f^\prime(x)&=&\int_0^1\frac{d}{dx}(|x-t|^3)\,dt\\
&=&\int_0^13(x-t)|x-t|\,dt\\
&=&-\left[|x-t|^3\right]_0^1\\
&=&-\left[(x-t)^2|x-t|\right]_0^1\\
&=&x^2|x|-(x-1)^2|x-1|
\end{eqnarray}

which is an increasing function and has no minimum.

Comment: The theorem is the [Leibnitz Integral Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule). And yes, the derivative for absolute value is undefined where it vanishes.

Comment: Actually that modulus is derivable everywhere because it is cubed. If it was simple modulus it wouldn;t be derivable . My error.

Comment: @amarius8312 That is correct. $|x|^\prime=\dfrac{x}{|x|}$ and we have $(|x|^n)^\prime=nx|x|^{n-2}$.